# Solve for reals: $a^2+b^2-ab-b+\frac 13=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, solution-verification

> Solve for reals: $$a^2+b^2-ab-b+\frac 13=0$$

My attempt.

[image]

$$\frac {d}{da} \left(a^2+b^2-ab-b+\frac 13\right)=0$$

$$2a-b=0$$

$$\frac {d}{db} \left(a^2+b^2-ab-b+\frac 13\right)=0$$

$$2b-a-1=0$$

And I got $a=\frac 13, b=\frac 23$

If I define $$f(a,b)=a^2+b^2-ab-b+\frac 13$$

Then is it correct using partial derivatives to find $(a,b)$ ?

I am aware completing the square method. But, I want to know the errors of this method I use.

Here are a graph $z = x^2 - xy + y^2 - y$  in 3-D  (vertical is distorted,  not sure how to fix that, although carefully adjusting $x,y$  bounds might work)

Also a contour plot. Ellipses

Found out how to adjust the $x,y$ bounds, this version seems better
[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141039/discussion-on-question-by-user1094359-solve-for-reals-a2b2-ab-b-frac-130).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's wrong. I think the problem is within a naive understanding of the terms you're using. Think about it this way and I hope it will help you:

You attempted to differentiate by $a$, and by some induction I suppose we can agree that it is **as valid as** differentiating by $b$. Then ask, what are the objects that we can differentiate at all? They are **functions**! Not the expressions. What are the symbols we use in the differentiation? They are the arguments (I'll call them parameters) of the function. So since you can't differentiate a zero, but only a function that is zero everywhere and since we are assuming that the functions are parametrized (I am being a little bit informal here) by $a$ and $b$, we deduce that the zero represents a function (in terms) of $a$ and $b$ that is equal to zero everywhere. Then the implication $f=g\Rightarrow\partial f=\partial g$ (one by which you allowed yourself to deduce $\partial f=\partial g$) means that we are assuming that the functions are equal. But in your case they are clearly not equal because it is easy to find a pair of $a$ and $b$ (formally, an element of the domain) for which they differ: for example $a=1$ and $b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2+b^2-ab-b+ \frac{1}{3} = \left( a - \frac{b}{2}  \right)^2  + \frac{3}{4} \left( b - \frac{2}{3}  \right)^2   $$

Comment: Please, see my question. I am aware completing the square, I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: @user1094359  I stopped reading once I saw that you were differentiating something.

Comment: OP explicitly wrote *“I am aware completing the square method. But, I want to know the errors of this method I use.”* So this does not answer the question at all.